# Some intuition behind the properties of intersection number.

Tags: intuition, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory, motivation

In the study of algebraic curves,we define intersection number of $F$ and $G$ at a point $p$ to be $I(F\cap G,p)=\dim_K(\mathcal O_p(\mathbb A^2)/\langle F,G\rangle$.But it is a rather unintuitive definition to me.In fact, I am cofused between intersection multiplicity and intersection number at $p$.Also it is not clear to me why the intersection number should have the following properties:

$1.$ $I(F\cap G,p)\geq m_p(F)\cdot m_p(G)$ with equality exactly when they have no tangent lines in common at $p$.

$2.$The intersection numbers should add when we take union of curves i.e.if $F=\prod  
F_i^{r_i}$ and $G=\prod G_j^{s_j}$, then $I(F\cap G,p)=\sum_{i,j}r_is_j I(F_i\cap G_j,p)$.

$3.$ $I(p,F\cap G)=I(p,F\cap (G+AF))$ for any $A\in K[X,Y]$.

(*Note:* There are seven properties that determine a unique intersection number but I understand the motivation behind the other ones.Just having problem with these ones.)

I am looking for a little help.

Comment: who is $\mathbb A^2$? Are the curves *plane* curves?

Comment: A right paren seems to be missing in the formula at the end of the very first sentence.

Comment: Did you possibly mean a `\cdot` instead of a punctuation dot between both $m$–s in $m_p(F)\cdot m_p(G)$...?

Comment: @CiaPan Yes,actually.

Comment: @Giulio Yes they are plane curves.

Comment: Have you read the proofs of those facts (for example, on Fulton's book)? A good way to get some intuition about why things are true is to see why they are true.